# C# ResolveEventHandler dll

Tags: c#, dll

I have a C# .net 4 app that I am trying to implement Await Async with. I ended up using AsyncBridge from NuGet. This works great except I have to make sure the AsyncBridge.dll is located with my stand alone app. To get around this I tried to load the .dll on the fly as a embedded resource via

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

```
static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("EmbedAssembly.AsyncBridge.dll"))
            {
                byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
                return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            }

        }
```

My issue all the tutorials show the exception "could not load assembly" and they kick off the ResovleEventHandler. When my program crashes trying to find the dll it is a exception of below.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in System.WIndows.Forms.dll. Addition information: Could not load file or assembly 'AsyncBridge.

How could I kick off a similar event to read my the dll as a embedded resource from a System.IO.FIleLoadException?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just copy it in program.cs unless it exists?

Comment: Can you please provide sample code of how to copy it into program.cs? I assume your saying copy the dll file into program.cs?

Comment: No, I meant the code that copies the resource to file could be invoked from the Main method instead. Spares you a lot of brain work 

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet of how to invoke the resource file in the Main method? Using the ResolveEventHandler has not worked for me per my initial post.

Comment: Just put the code you have in the ResolveEventHandler into the Main method.